# Cannot SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX() Of JanusGraph-Index With SchemaStatus.DISCARDED

Tags: full-text-search, cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph, java-17

## Problem

Why is JanusGraph not dropping a discarded index?
I'm performance-evaluating graph-databases as of their latest releases that meet our needs.
I need to drop to remake the index for [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) testing: speed, stability, and scale.

```java
package org.janusgraph.core.schema;
public enum SchemaAction {
    // ...
    DROP_INDEX(Collections.singleton(SchemaStatus.DISCARDED)),
    // ...
}
```

Please note that on-topic, answers to this question posed here, and furthering comments to this specified setup, are always appreciated.

This intended for a [persistent backend JanusGraph server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/); not an [`'inmemory' gremlin server`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/inmemorybackend/).
So this data will not be cleared between events, logins, or restarts.
This [Cassandra-Server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/) is for a [persistent hosting service](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4881/hosting-server-web-hosting).
This not a [POC of a test POC](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/) within a [Gremlin-Console sample](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/).
Further evaluation will be applied upon the enabled index so no suggestions of clearing, deleting, or `inmemory` please.

## Reproduction

### Expectations

I was expecting the index to drop away so I could recreate the index with

```java
janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
```

But what actually happened was

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertex with id 521 was removed.
```

I tried seeing if this was another one of those implicit / automatic processes JanusGraph sometimes has.
`buildIndex()` automatically does its own `get()` / `call()`, `SchemaStatus.REGISTERED`, and `SchemaStatus.ENABLED`.
But when I comment out the `janusGraphManagement.commit()`, JanusGraph says it didn't drop the index.

```bash
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An index with name '_id' has already been defined
```

### Logs

#### With `janusGraphManagement.commit()`

```json
...
2023-05-16 11:00:01,455 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    _id:   DISCARDED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertex with id 521 was removed.
    at org.janusgraph.core.InvalidElementException.removedException(InvalidElementException.java:57)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.verifyAccess(AbstractVertex.java:93)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.AbstractVertex.query(AbstractVertex.java:140)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.types.vertices.JanusGraphSchemaVertex.getDefinition(JanusGraphSchemaVertex.java:97)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx.expireSchemaElement(StandardJanusGraphTx.java:1632)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.commit(ManagementSystem.java:252)
    at Test18.main(Test18.java:54)
...
```

#### Without `janusGraphManagement.commit()`

```json
... 

2023-05-16 10:19:28,787 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    _id:   DISCARDED
2023-05-16 10:19:28,798 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey): DISCARDED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An index with name '_id' has already been defined
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:220)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.checkIndexName(ManagementSystem.java:661)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.createCompositeIndex(ManagementSystem.java:728)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.access$300(ManagementSystem.java:130)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem$IndexBuilder.buildCompositeIndex(ManagementSystem.java:824)
    at Test18.main(Test18.java:35)
```

### Code

```java
        // ...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        g.V().drop().iterate();
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        logger.info(janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id") + ":\t" + janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id").getIndexStatus(propertyKey).toString());

        // ...

        if (SchemaStatus.DISCARDED.equals(janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id").getIndexStatus(propertyKey))){
            JanusGraphIndex janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
            janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
            janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphIndex, SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX).get();
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
            logger.info("SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
        }
        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id")) {
            janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
            janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
            JanusGraphIndex janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
            logger.info("index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
        }

        // ...
```

### Resources

1. [Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. [Java 11.0.19 (corretto-11)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html)
3. [JanusGraph 1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2)
4. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20)
5. [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
6. [Cassandra:latest [container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)
7. [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)

Comment: It's fine if you want to use `inmemory` to illustrate a point. Just please don't suggest switching to `inmemory` and then try to dismiss concerns of persistent data. I've tried to accommodate responders before that just get out of hand and off-topic. Moderators can't intervene either because I engaged in-good-faith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended-up with how `JanusGraphManagement` handles `updateIndex()`.

`JanusGraphIndex` will be "considered" the new `SchemaStatus` when asking with `getIndexStatus`.
This won't be true when awaiting with `awaitGraphIndexStatus().status()` .
The `ManagementSystem` only sees the same as after `janusGraphManagement.commit()`.
Then, a new `janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement()` will have to be made to compare that they say the `janusGraphIndex` says the same with both of them.

But, when performing a `SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX` this will not be true.
`janusGraphIndex` will maintain its status as `DISCARDED` until `janusGraphManagement.commit()` has occurred. This is a differing behavior to the rest of the `SchemaAction` handling.
This can be verified with the sample below.

## Logs

```json
2023-05-16 12:32:33,880 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    buildCompositeIndex 
janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):    ENABLED
2023-05-16 12:32:34,013 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey): ENABLED
2023-05-16 12:32:34,020 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX 
janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):    DISABLED
2023-05-16 12:32:34,177 [INFO] [o.j.g.o.j.IndexRemoveJob.Thread-19] ::   Index _id metrics: success-tx: 5 doc-updates: 0 succeeded: 0
...
2023-05-16 12:32:34,288 [INFO] [o.j.g.o.j.IndexRemoveJob.Thread-1] ::    Index _id metrics: success-tx: 21 doc-updates: 0 succeeded: 0
2023-05-16 12:32:34,401 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.m.ManagementSystem.Thread-1] ::  Index update job successful for [_id]
2023-05-16 12:32:34,409 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.m.GraphIndexStatusWatcher.main] ::   All 1 key(s) on index _id have status(es) [DISCARDED]
2023-05-16 12:32:34,411 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    SchemaAction.DISCARD_INDEX 
janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):    DISCARDED
2023-05-16 12:32:34,415 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX 
janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):    DISCARDED
2023-05-16 12:32:34,521 [INFO] [Main.main] ::    SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX 
janusGraphIndex:    null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Code

```java
        // ... 
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        JanusGraphIndex janusGraphIndex;

        if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id")) {
            janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
            janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
            logger.info("buildCompositeIndex \njanusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
        }
        janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
        if (SchemaStatus.ENABLED.equals(janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey))) {
            logger.info("index.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
            janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphIndex, SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX).get();
            logger.info("SchemaAction.DISABLE_INDEX \njanusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
        }
        if (SchemaStatus.DISABLED.equals((janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey)))) {
            janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
            janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
            janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphIndex, SchemaAction.DISCARD_INDEX).get();
            ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(janusGraph, "_id").status(SchemaStatus.DISCARDED).call();
            logger.info("SchemaAction.DISCARD_INDEX \njanusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
        }
        if (SchemaStatus.DISCARDED.equals((janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey)))) {
            janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
            janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
            janusGraphManagement.updateIndex(janusGraphIndex, SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX).get();
            for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
                if (!janusGraphManagement.containsGraphIndex("_id"))
                    break;
            logger.info("SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX \njanusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey):\t" + janusGraphIndex.getIndexStatus(propertyKey));
            janusGraphManagement.commit();
        }
        janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        janusGraphIndex = janusGraphManagement.getGraphIndex("_id");
        logger.info("SchemaAction.DROP_INDEX \njanusGraphIndex:\t" + janusGraphIndex);
        // ...
```